# Traverse tree based on timer

Tags: java, algorithm, swing

I'm trying to animate the traversal of a tree (BFS and DFS) to a JPanel using a `timer` and `paintComponent`... Kind of like so...

[image]

Right now the BFS algorithm just instantly loops through all nodes and paints visited nodes cyan... But I'd like to allow people to see how the tree is being traversed... node by node... So I'm trying to add a timer to delay when next `while loop` iteration runs... It's not working at all...

**Timer:**

```
public void timer() {
    int initialDelay = 1000;
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            if (cancelTimer) {
                timer.cancel();
            }   
            if (counter == 3) {
                //reset 
                counter = 0;
            }
            if (counter < 3) {
                ++counter;
                System.out.println(counter);
            }       
        }
    }, initialDelay, 1000); 
}
```

**paintComponent: repaints the nodes as they're traversed**

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

    g.setColor(rootNode.getColor());
    g.fillRect(rootNode.getX(), rootNode.getY(), rootNode.getWidth(), rootNode.getHeight());

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.drawString(rootNode.getValue(), rootNode.getX()+9, rootNode.getY()+16);
    paintComponent(g, rootNode);    
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g, Nodes parentNode) {  
    //keep generating new nodePrintList to load with new Children
    ArrayList<Nodes> nodePrintList = new ArrayList<Nodes>();    

    //base case: end of nodeList
    if (nodeList.indexOf(parentNode)==nodeList.size()-1) {
        System.out.println("\nend");
    }
    else {  
    //traverse nodeList recursively 
        nodePrintList = getChildren(parentNode);    
        //loop through and print all children of node n
        //System.out.println();
        int x = parentNode.getX()-50;

        for (Nodes child : nodePrintList) {             
            g.setColor(child.getColor());
            child.setX(x);
            child.setY(parentNode.getY()+50);
            g.fillRect(child.getX(), child.getY(), child.getWidth(), child.getHeight());        
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.drawString(child.getValue(), child.getX()+9, child.getY()+16);
            x+=50;
            //System.out.print("PARENT: " + parentNode.getValue() + " | x,y: " + parentNode.getX() + ", " + parentNode.getY() + "...\n CHILD: " + child.getValue() + " | x,y: " + child.getX() + ", " + child.getY());  
            paintComponent(g, child);
            g.drawLine(parentNode.getX()+10, parentNode.getY()+23, child.getX()+10, child.getY());
        }           
    }
    repaint();

}
```

**BFS():**

```
public void bfs() {

    Queue q = new LinkedList();
    q.add(rootNode);
    rootNode.visited(true);
    rootNode.setColor(Color.cyan);
    printNode(rootNode);
    //only perform check when counter = 10;
    while (!q.isEmpty()) {          
        Nodes n = (Nodes)q.remove();
        Nodes child = null;
        //put all unvisited children in the queue
        while ((child = getUnvisitedChildNode(n)) != null)
        {           
            if (counter == 3) {
                child.visited(true);
                printNode(child);
                q.add(child);
                child.setColor(Color.cyan); 
            }
        }
    }
    if (q.isEmpty()) {
        cancelTimer = true;
        //RepaintManager.currentManager(this).markCompletelyClean(this);
    }
}
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a timer object with the same name as a function? This is probably not the best practice....

Comment: 1. util.Timer can be used for AWT Canvas/Panel, but not never for JPanel with paintComponent, use Swing Timer

2. never to touch the RepaintManager in Swing, but is possible and I used that,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could, for example, create a `Queue<Nodes>` that will accept the nodes for painting. Namely, in your `bfs()` method, where you set the color `child.setColor(Color.cyan);` add this Node to a `Queue`. So:

```
if (counter == 3) {
    child.visited(true);
    printNode(child);
    q.add(child);
    paintQueue.add(child);
}
```

And in the timer, at fixed delay, `poll` this queue and paint the node:

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        if (!paintQueue.isEmpty()) {
            Nodes node= paintQueue.poll();
            node.setColor(Color.cyan);
        }     
    }
}, initialDelay, 1000);
```